# Don't have permission to access / on this server (apache2) in docker

Tags: django, apache, docker, mod-wsgi, dockerfile

I am trying to host Django project in Docker using apache2 server. I am starting the apache server manually and able to access the default site. But when I configure the 000-default.config file I am getting error You don't have permission to access / on this server.

This is my 000-default.config file

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot /code/demo
    WSGIScriptAlias / /code/demo/app/wsgi.py
    <Directory "/code/demo/backup">
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER kketan@somemail.com
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y --force-yes install build-essential
RUN apt-get -y --force-yes install python python-pip python-dev
RUN apt-get -y --force-yes install libffi-dev libssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes libmysqlclient-dev
RUN mkdir /code
ADD evn_packages.txt /code
ADD python_packages.txt /code
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN apt-get install -y mariadb-server
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r python_packages.txt
RUN apt-get install -y vim
ADD django /code
EXPOSE 8000
RUN apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

I am importing Django project from the same directory shown above. Even with the default Django server is able to run the project but not able to access the it in the browser. I have also changed the port listen to 8000 as it was not working on default port 80.

I am new to docker, am I missing and permission giving in Dockerfile? Can you also share some links how to host Django project using apache2 in Docker as I am not able to find good content on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start:

```
<Directory "/code/ilab/backup">
```

should be:

```
<Directory "/code/demo/app">
```

In general it is a bad idea to be trying to build a Docker image from scratch yourself as there is lots to learn to do things the right way. Another problem with what you are doing for example is sending logs to a file in the container when they should be sent to stdout/stderr so Docker can capture them.

You might want to try and find pre built images which set everything up for you properly and make it relatively easy to then deploy your application. As an example look out how things are done with:

- https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi-docker